# Error C1001 “Internal Compiler Error”.Error points to {

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

I am working in Visual studio CLR for the first time, and everytime I debug the program, I get  an error C1001 in `MyForm.h` on the line 16. The only thing that is in line 16 is a `{` symbol.Here is the picture:

[image]

So, can anyone help?

Comment: This looks like an IntelliSense error message. (IntelliSense is known to make wrong reports from time to time.) So, please check whether you can compile the code and check what the Build _Output_ complaints. (That's IMHO the only trust-able. I even disabled the Error List in my VS.) Concerning _Internal Compiler Error_: I've seen them from time to time over the years. That's annoying as it indicates that the compiler works not completely as it is supposed to. However, in every single case the reason was a mistake in my code though it's, of course, harder to find with such an unspecific error.

Comment: _The only thing that is in line 16 is a `{` symbol._ The error position indicates where the compiler found something which isn't matching the rule it started before. This can also mean that it started a rule before which you didn't intend. So, if `{` is something which hardly can be wrong start to search backwards whether you can find your mistake above. (I.e. get used to the fact that compilers don't read the code like humans do. - They don't see the big picture.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure whether this is an answer to OPs question but this was such a nice incidence that I couldn't resist to post it.

---

This is what I wrote in my comment (earlier this day):

> This looks like an IntelliSense error message. (IntelliSense is known to make wrong reports from time to time.) So, please check whether you can compile the code and check what the Build Output complaints. (That's IMHO the only trust-able. I even disabled the Error List in my VS.)

This is what happened just today to me (in Visual Studio 2019):

[image: Snapshot of VS 2019]

Please, note the red zig-zag line under `fOut` and the tool tip with `internal error`.

I was uncertain, at least, a moment whether I could've made a mistake. (I must admit that I trust IntelliSense to a certain degree because most of its complaints are correct.)
Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to compile this file…

Output:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: RFFileUtils - Example 1 - u8path(), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>RFFStreamExample.cc
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```